# OnClickListener Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm trying to create an application for Android, but when I try to start it with 2 `setOnClickListener`, it crashes,
Infact if i delete one of the two events it doesen't crash
how can I do?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english, but im italian

MainActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that wil return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.FeedBackHome);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        }
    });



    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NotReg);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class));
        }
    });




}
```

Comment: Post your crash log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first illegal code :

you can't set new Content View onClick like you do here :

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.contact); // <-- this is wrong
    }
});
```

2. be sure that  `Register.class` contain layout and able to open from another activity.

Comment: Yup this is the problem, you must do something different in your FAB (not set content view)

Comment: @Yazan exactly : )